# LGBM not varying predictions with random state

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am trying to compute prediction intervals for a classifier.

I trained in sklearn. Even after setting a new `random_state` parameter in my pipeline, it doesn't seem to change my results when refitting on the data. What can I do about this?

This is a relevant snippet of the code I'm using:

```
SEED_VALUE = 3
t_clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('lgbm',
                        LGBMClassifier(class_weight="balanced",
                        random_state=SEED_VALUE, max_depth=20,
                        min_child_samples=20, num_leaves=31))
                        ])
states = [0,1,2,3]

for state in states:   
    train_temp = train.copy()
    t_clf.set_params(lgbm__random_state=state)
    t_clf.fit(train_temp, train_temp['label'])
    t_clf.predict_proba(test)   

# output from predict probability doesn't change with varying states
```

The same occurs when trying to change shuffle order or bagging seed.

Here are my current parameters if this is helpful to know:

```
LGBMClassifier(bagging_seed=2, boosting_type='gbdt', class_weight='balanced',
               colsample_bytree=1.0, importance_type='split', learning_rate=0.1,
               max_depth=50, min_child_samples=1, min_child_weight=0.001,
               min_data_in_leaf=10, min_split_gain=0.0, n_estimators=100,
               n_jobs=-1, num_leaves=30, objective=None, random_state=1,
               reg_alpha=0.0, reg_lambda=0.0, silent=True, subsample=1.0,
               subsample_for_bin=200000, subsample_freq=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get the same results regardless of the random seed is because no random sampling is performed at any stage with your model specification. If for instance you set `colsample_bytree` to a value less than 1 then you will see different predicted probabilities for different random seeds.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier

# generate some data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=50, random_state=100)

# set the random state
for state in [0, 1, 2, 3]:

    # instantiate the classifier
    clf = LGBMClassifier(
        class_weight='balanced',
        max_depth=20,
        min_child_samples=20,
        num_leaves=31,
        random_state=state,
        colsample_bytree=0.1,
    )

    # fit the classifier
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # predict the class probabilities
    y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X)

    # print the predicted probability of the 
    # first class for the first sample 
    print([state, format(y_pred[0, 0], '.4%')])

    # [0, '97.8132%']
    # [1, '97.4980%']
    # [2, '98.3729%']
    # [3, '98.0737%']
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed a change when reshuffling with replacement which didn't require me to have to change the random seeds, but I will try this as well. For future readers, this means doing the following before fitting: new_train = train.copy().sample(frac=1,replace=True); It is critical to ensure replace argument is True which is why shuffling failed before.